# Is the file transfer between GCS and App Engine secured by HTTPS?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

My app downloads and uploads files to GCS -- I looked through the GCS client docs and couldn't find a flag to secure the file transfer. Is HTTPS enabled by default for these transfers?

Reading through [GCS docs](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/concepts-techniques#encryption):

> The data is automatically and transparently decrypted when read by an authorized user.

Is the data stored in plain text as it makes the GCS -> App Engine transfer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GAE GCS client is using HTTPS for interaction with GCS.
for Java see: https://code.google.com/p/appengine-gcs-client/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/java/com/google/appengine/tools/cloudstorage/oauth/OauthRawGcsService.java#154
" return new URI("https", null, STORAGE_API_HOSTNAME, -1, path, query, null).toURL();"
and for Python
https://code.google.com/p/appengine-gcs-client/source/browse/trunk/python/src/cloudstorage/storage_api.py#89
" api_url = 'https://storage.googleapis.com'"